# Append unequal length of values from a list to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary, the keys of which are:

```
{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
```

and some examples of list values:

```
1- [(33.0, 134), (54.0, 113), (21.0, 120)]
2- [(25.0, 153)]
3- [()]
```

I want to apply the list values to the dictionary keys in order. The expected output will be
 in case 1-:

```
{'A' : 33.0,
'B' : 134,
'C' : 54.0,
'D' : 113}
```

in case 2-:

```
{'A' : 25.0,
'B' : 153,
'C' : NaN,
'D' : NaN}
```

in case 3-:

```
{'A' : NaN,
'B' : NaN,
'C' : NaN,
'D' : NaN}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a dictionary comprehension - substitute `'NaN'` for `np.nan` if that's the value you're after.

```
>>> keys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

>>> l = [(33.0, 134), (54.0, 113), (21.0, 120)]
>>> dict(zip(keys,([x for sl in l for x in sl]+['NaN']*len(keys))[:len(keys)]))
{'A': 33.0, 'B': 134, 'C': 54.0, 'D': 113}

>>> l = [(25.0, 153)]
>>> dict(zip(keys,([x for sl in l for x in sl]+['NaN']*len(keys))[:len(keys)]))
{'A': 25.0, 'B': 153, 'C': 'NaN', 'D': 'NaN'}

>>> l = [(,)]
>>> dict(zip(keys,([x for sl in l for x in sl]+['NaN']*len(keys))[:len(keys)]))
{'A': 'NaN', 'B': 'NaN', 'C': 'NaN', 'D': 'NaN'}
```

**Explanation:**

We use `zip()` to zip the keys list of size `n` with the flattened list of tuples, appending a list of `n` `'NaN'` values to the end, and then chopping off the first `n` values. The `dict()` constructor accepts a zipped list as an argument.

Comment: Hi, I am total beginner. So I don't understand the code. Can u please explain me. It Wil be a great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is too complicated, you could implement it easily:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

keys = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') # use any ordered sequence

mapping = {
    1: [(33.0, 134), (54.0, 113), (21.0, 120)],
    2: [(25.0, 153)],
    3: [()]
}

print(dict(zip_longest(keys, chain.from_iterable(mapping[2]))))
```